# Apache2 passenger cause error 500 on simple rails app

Tags: ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, server

I have install ruby 2.2.0 with rails 4.1.7 I tried installing passenger everything goes fine, now when i access my virtual host i get 500 internal server error, i've tried adding index.html file in public directory of my app and it is working,
change chwon permission to $USER:www-data, changed permission to 777 to all files and folder but still i am getting the 500 error,
one important thing is happens that i had by mistakenly written "rot" instead of "root" in routs.rb and when i tried the its comes up with passenger error page which was read error in my routes.rb file then i fix it but again getting 500 error.

here is my apache error.log

```
    majid@majid-Ubuntu:/var/www/html/test_rails/log$ tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
    [ 2014-12-17 19:39:52.0171 19305/7fdd41798700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:298 ]: Preloader for /var/www/html/test_rails started on PID 19337, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.19298/generation-0/backends/preloader.p0p9xl
    App 19506 stdout: 
    App 19337 stderr: Passenger RackApp: /var/www/html/test_rails: symbol lookup   error: /home/majid/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0-dev/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.55/buildout/ruby/ruby-2.2.0-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so: undefined symbol: rb_thread_blocking_region
    [Wed Dec 17 19:39:53.033168 2014] [core:error] [pid 19320] [client 127.0.0.1:55690] End of script output before headers: 
    [ 2014-12-17 19:39:58.0277 19305/7fdd4187c700 Pool2/Pool.h:785 ]: Process (pid=19506, group=/var/www/html/test_rails#default) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.
    App 19525 stdout: 
    App 19337 stderr: Passenger RackApp: /var/www/html/test_rails: symbol lookup error: /home/majid/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0-dev/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.55/buildout/ruby/ruby-2.2.0-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so: undefined symbol: rb_thread_blocking_region
    [Wed Dec 17 19:44:06.177450 2014] [core:error] [pid 19321] [client 127.0.0.1:55734] End of script output before headers: 
    [ 2014-12-17 19:44:08.0296 19305/7fdd4187c700 Pool2/Pool.h:785 ]: Process (pid=19525, group=/var/www/html/test_rails#default) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.
            App 19843 stdout:
```

Comment: You've got an incompatible library somewhere in your system: `passenger_native_support.so: undefined symbol: rb_thread_blocking_region` The library has not been compiled with the symbol shown and therefore fails when trying to look it up.

Comment: Yes you are right, what should I do? should i re-install phusion passenger and try installing again?

Comment: I believe Ruby 2.2 support was added in Passenger 4.0.55.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installed passenger and and configure vhost as it says, there were some setting in rails app environments. now its working perfectly.. :)